# Mellow with the iPhone 5 yellow?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, iphone-5

I am building an app which uses some nice calm green and yellow colours.

However, on the iPhone 5 'yellow screen' theses colours lose their charm and are actually quite sharp.

My question is: **is the iPhone 5 yellow screen so common that I should accept it, and design for it?**

There doesn't seem to be any clear answers out there. Would appreciate some other developer / designer views on the situation.

Comment: None of the people I know have the problem with yellow screens, and if I had, I would go to Apple and return it - so I don't think this is a common thing.

Comment: I've got a 'yellow screen' iphone 5, and there does seem to have been a lot of complaints about them online. But how many are out there? And are they still being produced? And is the 'glue drying' theory true?

Comment: Thanks to whoever for the -1! I am asking a legitimate question I am not a Apple hater.

Comment: I didn't give you -1 but I guess the problem is, that this is not a question that fits the purpose of StackOverflow. Your question cannot be answered, it can only be discussed.

Comment: I think it does warrant a StackOverflow question. I cannot be the only developer / designer who has questioned whether or not these screens are so common that they should be considered when developing a new app. I would really like to know how common these yellow screens are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get any definite info about how much iPhones do have the yellow screen issue. The only one who can have this information is Apple and they surely won't give it out to the public.

My guess is, that there are relatively few iPhones with that problem since people who have the issue will report back on forums, while people without won't. Even if it's 20% of all devices (which I doubt, my guess would be something like 1-2%), I think it wouldn't make sense to adjust your design for those devices, unless you already have one in mind that's as good as your current one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer jimpic. I appreciate it is hard to get a very accurate answer on this topic but I do think it is valid. There are MANY questions/answers on Stackflow which are subjective (to varying degrees).